# How does one recieves the Block solving reward of 12.5 bitcoin(currently) when he solves the block of transaction?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

In solving the problem of bitcoin blocks who reward the solver of block.
suppose i has a address as public key 
7671312fhd3213

and solve the block of transaction who decides that i must get a money ???

since my proof of work will be sent to all the peer of the network 
who issue the bitcoin transaction of 25 bitcoin or 12.5 $ reward to my 
public key ??

Comment: Voting to close because not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

The miner itself includes a special transaction in the block called generation transaction. Every block only has a single generation transaction.

This generation transaction transfers the block subsidy plus the fees of the block to an address controlled by the miner.

For instance, if you look at block [434868](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000000a24f915e539e6a2c57c65a9fbddd6b4178c42eb391b8e1), there is a single generation transaction that transfers 12.96 to address 17ggdTQzKFwrKP1zgqb5Kjuw6CpGKaE6Jrw

thanks to [disckjet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/3041/disckjet)